# how to program a button from main view controller to open another view controller - firestore records

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, tableview, viewcontroller

I'm building my first app using Swift and have done a few modules from the CodeWithChris website.  I'm just doing this as a hobby.

The main ViewController has a tableView with a list of records that are retrieved from FireStore.  If you click one of the records, it will open another ViewController through a prepare for segue function and brings up a detail screen with various fields from that record for editing.

So back to the main view: In the tableView prototype cell, I have a horizontal stack view in which has two of the fields from the record and then I've added a button which I'd like to open a separate View different from the first I've described above but similar - so that it will bring up a detailed record view but with an entirely different set of fields that the other.

The concept is I'm tracking animal health histories so it shows a list of the animal names and types and when you click on the name or type, it goes to that first view with details about that animal.  Then from that main tableview, I have a button that I want to bring up the vaccination history.  I tried to do a prepare for segue by dragging the button to a new view controller but that didn't seem to work.

I'm just looking for the general idea of what I have to do and can probably use that feedback to maybe figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The segue identifier lets me set up some conditions within the prepare for segue function to active my goal!